# Express sessions behaving differently: How can I prevent my session from being destroyed after a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express

I am using express/node.js to create a simple auth system, and am using sessions for the login of course. In app.js, here is my session configuration code:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'Viu65Cc5VTU6cu',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));
```

As far as i know, once i set a session like `req.session.session_name` It should all work fine. Instead, after a successful authentication I assign the user's id to a session called user id.

```
req.session.user_id  = doc.id;
```

I then would expect this value to remain until i call a destroy function, or close the browser. However, the second I respond to a POST request (on a different part of the app) i console.log the session to see if it is working and exists, however i get "undefined". No matter where I call the console.log i will get undefined. The session also seems to end after a page refresh which slightly contradicts the point of a session does it not?
Maybe the configuration is wrong? Or is this how express sessions are meant to behave?

Thanks in advance if you can offer any suggestions.

P.S when i originally set the session, i tried console.log the value immediately afterwards and i do get a valid value. After that it seems to become undefined .

Comment: Are you using HTTPS?

Comment: No, its just a standard ubuntu server with little security

Answer (score 2):

The cookie setting `secure : true` will only work if you're accessing your site over https, as [documented here](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookie-options).

Otherwise, a session cookie will not be set, which basically means that a session won't persist between page requests.

Comment: So i need to set it to false?

Comment: @CasparWylie correct, although `false` may also be the default (not sure).